# E-cig (and especially Liquid bottles) in hand luggage on a flight from Zurich to Madrid

Tags: hand-luggage, madrid, smoking, e-cigarettes

I will be flying from Zurich to Madrid next weekend and I am not sure if e-cig and some liquid bottles are allowed in my hand luggage. I only have hand luggage for pricing reasons.

If liquid bottles are not allowed in hand luggage, can I take pre-filled Pods (e.g. from Vuse, a large tobacco company).

I searched Track Stack Exchange and found some interesting questions about e-cigs, although they are a bit older and laws may have changed.

Comment: Have you contacted your airline or even read their instructions? However, according to online sources it should be okay: https://www.vuse.com/gb/en/blog/guides/can-you-take-vapes-on-a-plane

Answer (score 3):

Like anything containing a liquid, you should put them in your toiletries bag. Each container should be no larger than 100ml, and the (single) bag should be no more than 1l.

Also the e-cigarette will contain a Lithium-Ion battery and is constrained by the rules described [here](https://www.iata.org/contentassets/6fea26dd84d24b26a7a1fd5788561d6e/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf). Check the dedicated section on the topic on page 2.